# Duplicate class found in modules (exclude packages)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have added 2 modules in my project but I got the following error

```
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl found in modules jetified-XXX-XXX-XXX_XXX_0.2-runtime (com.github.YYY:YYY:YYYY_0.2) and jetified-XXX-XXX-XXX-1.0.24-runtime (com.github.XXX:XXX-XXX-XXX:1.0.24)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedRequestManagerFactory found in modules jetified-YYY-YYY-YYY_0.2-runtime (com.github.nithraedu:YYYY-YYY:YYY_0.2) and jetified-XXX-XXX-XXX-1.0.24-runtime (com.github.XXX:XXX-XXX-XXX:1.0.24)
```

how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you have duplicate classes, it shows that you have added dependencies that use the same modules and classes so you must find these dependencies and exclude the duplicates. In your case I think you want to use glide library so you can simply add:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

In your app level build.gradle file. This is an issue for some of the dependencies that used same classes before AndroidX. The other option for you is to simply migrate to AndroidX which solves these kinds of problems.

if you want to see your dependency_tree and identify what's causing the duplication you can use this command:

```
gradle -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile
```

or you can find your dependency_tree in view -> tool-windows -> gradle -> YourAppName -> tasks -> android -> androidDependencies

after that you must find the duplicated module and exclude it from the library dependency to avoid duplication for example:

```
  implementation('com.example.m:m:1.0') {
     exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'x 
  }
```

Comment: but i am using 

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

Comment: i am changing following but same problem coming

Comment: implementation('com.github.example:example_A_Module:1.0.25') {
        exclude group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', module: 'glide'
    }
   
 implementation('com.github.example:example_B_Module:1.0.4') {
        exclude group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', module: 'glide'
    }
   
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
   
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

Comment: Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl found in modules jetified-example_B_Module-1.0.4-runtime (com.github.example:example_B_Module:1.0.4) and jetified-example_A_Module-1.0.24-runtime (com.github.example:example_A_Module:1.0.25)



Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedRequestManagerFactory found in modules jetified-example_B_Module-1.0.4-runtime (com.github.example:example_B_Module:1.0.4) and jetified-example_A_Module-1.0.24-runtime (com.github.example:example_A_Module:1.0.25)
@Afshin Samiei

Comment: give me the list of your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#avoid-appglidemodule-in-libraries

The libraries which you are using glide and it extends the AppGlideModule instead of LibraryGlideModule.